# Silent install of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am using a normal user account with limited admin privileges. I need to install `SQLSP3.exe` with admin privileges in silent mode.

This is the command I am executing, but it's not able to proceed:

```
start /WAIT C:\Temp\SQLSP3.exe /qs /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Action=Patch /AllInstances /w
```

Comment: What is the question? With limited admin privileve, it will probably fail with or without silent mode.

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so: please **post them** here! We can't see your screen, nor read your mind ......

Comment: I am running this BAT file from another command file with following code         runas.exe /profile /user:administrator "C:\temp\SQLSP3.bat", and while executing UAC windows pops up for entering password.   Is there any option where i can code the Administrator Password in any of the Script file ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Option explicit 
dim oShell 
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.Run "runas /user:Domain\administrator ""C:\Temp\SQLSP3.bat""" 
WScript.Sleep 100 
oShell.Sendkeys "Password~" 
Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is [tag:vbscript] code, but your question is not tagged accordingly! so you should add that tag to your question; otherwise this answer is off-topic...